# In Gin-Rummy, how likely is that a round ends in a Draw?

Tags: statistics, gin-rummy

In Gin-Rummy, when the deck reach the last two cards and no player have knocked, the rounds end in a draw.  In games of experts, or at least experienced players, **how often a round ends in a draw**? I would like to get an estimation of an expert.

- [Playing To the Wall in a Defensive Manner](http://rummytalk.com/playing-to-the-wall-in-a-defensive-manner/) explains well when it is smart to play for the wall.
- Terminology: a game consist of several rounds; a round consist of several turns. A game can never end in a draw, since in each round only a single player receive points.

Comment: Are you assuming that experienced players will knock if they can, (whether at the first opportunity or when they see the draw pile getting low)? In that case we'd be looking for an estimate of how often you can get through the pack with neither player being able to knock at any point, and assuming they made a reasonable decision every turn.

Comment: yes, I agree.  I would like to see some data set of experts players and their likelihood to hit the Wall.

Comment: I can't help you there, then. I'm a novice, learning it with my daughter. I considered whether it might be possible to model a round. Probabilities are one thing but modelling the decision-making process is another

Comment: That said, it must be pretty rare. Whenever we've got near the end of the draw pile, one or both of us has always been able to go out, and for a while, but been trying to reduce deadwood (often chasing the same cards). But "pretty rare" wouldn't be much of an answer

Answer (score 1):

I have played Gin often with my family, at least several hundred rounds. I do not recall ever having participated in a game which ended in a draw.

I will note that I have primarily participated in two-player games, logic indicates that games with additional players would have a higher probability of ending in a draw as there would be fewer rounds per player and each additional player results in one card per round that cannot be accessed.

Comment: We might need to clearify some terminology.  A game consist of several rounds, a round consist of several turns.   A game can never end in a draw, since in each round one player (at most) recieve points.  hitting the wall is when a round ends in a draw (happens when the deck gets to the last 2 cards and no one knocks).